# Bazel go_binary c-shared link mode: Where is the header?

Tags: go, bazel

I'm trying to use Bazel (v1.0.0) rules_go to build header + library as I would with go build `-buildmode=c-archive`. I have the following rule set up in my BUILD.bzl file:

```
go_binary(
   name="go_cpp_bridge",
   srcs = ["cpp_bridge.go"],
   cgo = True,
   gc_linkopts=["-buildmode=c-shared"],
   linkmode = "c-archive",
   visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
 )
```

The current code of `cpp_bridge.go` is just a hello world to see if it works:

```
package main

import "C"

//export Add
func Add(a, b int) int { return a + b }

func main(){}
```

Bazel does generate a library file, but I'm missing the associated header file in the bazel-bin output. Testing with go build yields both header file and library. How do I get Bazel to give me the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `linkmode = "c-shared"` and `linkmode = "c-archive"` are defined, there are a few additional targets that are defined by adding a suffix to the end of the `go_binary` name. So for example, you can build `go_cpp_bridge.c_hdrs` to get the header file. You can build `go_cpp_bridge.cc` for a `cc_library` that can be linked with other C/C++ targets. The header is named after the `go_binary` rule (so `go_cpp_bridge.h`).

To extend your example, here's a working build file:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_binary")

go_binary(
    name = "go_cpp_bridge",
    srcs = ["cpp_bridge.go"],
    cgo = True,
    linkmode = "c-archive",
)

cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.c"],
    deps = [":go_cpp_bridge.cc"],
)
```

And a C program that links against Go:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "go_cpp_bridge.h"

int main() {
  printf("%lld\n", Add(21, 21));
  return 0;
}
```

This isn't documented because it's not a great interface. Since this was implemented, Bazel has added better ways to write C/C++ compatible rules, but rules_go doesn't support that yet. [#2176](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/2176) is the tracking issue for that.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer! This looks great. However, when compiling the C part, the header is still not found, although it gets generated in the Bazel bin directory.

Comment: OK, the solution works, very nice! However, the last piece of the puzzle is to define the proper path to the include, this will follow your worskpace structure. I.e., if main.c is in "foo/bar/" then you need to include "foo/bar/go_cpp_bridge.h"